# Set multiple triggers to background task

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have problem setting more then one trigger to my background task. Is it allowed to set multiple triggers to one task? I can't find any documentation about working with more than one SetTrigger statements.

The problem is that, when I run my app, myTrigger fires as I want it to, but the TimeTrigger won't fire. I've let it run during whole night but without any change. It hasn't started.

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
builder.SetTrigger(new TimeTrigger(15, false));
builder.SetTrigger(myTrigger);  
...
await myTrigger.RequestAsync();
```

Thank you very much.

EDIT (Firing only `syncTrigger` still. I'm waiting for almost hour.):

```
ApplicationTrigger syncTrigger = new ApplicationTrigger();

private void InitBackgroundTasks()
{
    IBackgroundCondition m_BKTaskCondition = new SystemCondition(SystemConditionType.InternetAvailable);

    var triggers = new List<IBackgroundTrigger> { new TimeTrigger(15, false), syncTrigger };
    var conditions = new List<IBackgroundCondition> { m_BKTaskCondition };

    var registrations = RegisterBackgroundTask(typeof(BackgroundSync).ToString(), nameof(BackgroundSync), triggers, conditions).ToList();

    registrations = registrations;
    // Both triggers are null

}

public IEnumerable<BackgroundTaskRegistration> RegisterBackgroundTask(string taskEntryPoint, string TaskName, IReadOnlyList<IBackgroundTrigger> triggers, IReadOnlyList<IBackgroundCondition> conditions)
{
    var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

    builder.Name = TaskName;
    builder.TaskEntryPoint = taskEntryPoint;

    BackgroundTaskRegistration registeredTask = null;

    foreach (var condition in conditions)
    {
        if (condition != null)
        {
            builder.AddCondition(condition);
        }
    }

    foreach (var trigger in triggers)
    {
        if (trigger != null)
        {
            builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        }

        try
        {
            registeredTask = builder.Register();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: RegisterBackgroundTask - {0}\n\n", ex.Message);
        }

        yield return registeredTask;
    }
}
```

TimeTrigger look fine, but syncTrigger don't - weird.
[image]

Comment: Change you Trigger method to accept a List<> object.  You 2nd trigger is over-writing the 1st trigger.

Comment: Have you tried to register the BTask twice - for each trigger?

Comment: have a look on [How to register multiple triggers and conditions for background task](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/207b4252-bf1f-4cc3-a0ec-49ea3062773e/how-to-register-multiple-triggers-and-conditions-for-background-task?forum=winappswithcsharp) might help you

Comment: I will try that - thank you guys.

Comment: @MohitShrivastava I'm trying what I see in your link (honestly I copy/paste it) but it's not working.

Comment: You can set more than one condition but you cannot set more than one trigger to background task. So you have to register two background tasks. Task_A - Trigger_A, Task_B - Trigger_B.

Comment: That's what I'm doing in `foreach` loop, didn't I?